# Email validate ( not only regex)

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, dns

I want to validate complete Email address.
I am not asking to match using pericular string.

but suppose someone enter email id a@bnm.com then first the bnm should be validated and if such domain found then also it should check for such a@bnm.com is available or invalid.???

Can anyone tell me how can i do this?>?>

Comment: Generally, to completely validate an email address you just send them an email with a link back to your site, so you can confirm that (a) the email address works and (b) it belongs to the person who just signed up with you

Comment: But even i dont want that fake registration done in my database..

Comment: What fake registration? Are you sending unsolicited email?

Comment: I mean that if user enter incorrect email id then he cant register into my system...He have to enter valid email address...

Comment: @Kishan Gajjar
: That's correct. Let's face it, if a user can't enter their own email correctly, you have a bigger problem.

Comment: Expire registrations that have not completed after some amount of time, like a day.

Answer (score 5):

Validating an email address and verifying the account actually exists are two very different things.

One way (and possibly the only effective way) to do this is at the end of the user registration process, send a 'reply required to confirm' email to the supplied email address (after checking the format is correct).

As Greg Hewgill noted, you should expire registrations that do not receive a reply in a certain time period, say 7 days.

Comment: @kishan: it's not a "fake registration". Quite the opposite in fact.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use some Email validation service for verifing if they exists. I have found one for you [Best Coding Pratices](http://www.bestcodingpractices.com/email_validation_service-2718.html), well this is a free service and has some limitations on it.

If you dont like it you can google for other email validation services.